# Incompatible Pointer Type issue While Copying String and Printing To a File

Tags: c

I get two warnings of the same type with this code compiling with GCC.

> warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char *[1001]' to parame

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>    

    char line[1001]; // The line supports up to a 1000 characters
    char *lines[11][1001]; // An array of lines (up to 10 lines where each line is a 1000 characters max)

    int main(){

        int 
        i, // Line number
        j; // Length of the line
        char result[100], text[100];
        FILE *file;

        strcpy(text, "String No."); // The default text

        file = fopen("test.txt", "w+"); // Open the file for reading and writing

        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // Loop to create a line.

            if(i != 9){ // If the line is NOT at the 10th string

                sprintf(result, "%s%d, ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result

            }
            else{

                sprintf(result, "%s%d ", text, i); // Format the text and store it in result            

            }

            printf("%s", result); // Display the result variable to the screen

            strncat(line, result, 15); // Concatenate all strings in one line

        }

        strncat(line, "\n\n", 2); // Add a new-line character at the end of each line

        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ // Now loop to change the line.

            strcpy(lines[i], line); // Copy the line of text into each line of the array

            fputs(lines[i], file); // Put each line into the file        

        }

        fclose(file);  

    }
```

By the looks of it, this fix should be quite simple, just that I haven't thought of it or come by it yet. Thanks!

Comment: Think again about the type of `lines`... What is it *really*? What is the type of `lines[i]`?

Comment: `char *lines[11][1001];` -> `char lines[11][1001];`

Comment: Wonderful. That was that.

Comment: OT: regarding: `file = fopen("test.txt", "w+");` when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "fopen failed" );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The call to `perror()` will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: regarding: `file = fopen("test.txt", "w+");`  Why open the file for both reading and writing when the posted code only writes to the file I.E. never reads from the file?

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
char *lines[11][1001];
```

this is a huge array of pointers, Not an array of eleven arrays of 1001 characters. Suggest:

```
char lines[11][1001];
```

BTW: why 11 arrays of characters when only 10 are used?

BTW: why 1001 characters when the max is 15*10 = 150 characters?